# How to count the number of occurences of n-length combinations of characters in string

Tags: bash, perl, permutation

I am using the following one liner to list the occurrences of combinations of `ATCG`, forming string of length 6. It works fine aside from not printing the occurrence of 0 matches. Is there a way to change the regex, or another part, to where it will print something like "0 ATTTAG"?

```
#!/bin/bash
for file in e_coli.fa
do
    base=$(basename $file .fa)
    cat $file | perl -nE 'say for /(?<=([ATCG]{6}))/g' \
        | sort | uniq -c >> ${base}_hexhits_6mer.txt
done

stdout:
    465 AAAAAA
    607 AAAAAC
    661 AAAAAG
    581 AAAAAT
    563 AAAACA
    807 AAAACC
    770 AAAACG
    373 AAAACT
    663 AAAAGA
   1213 AAAAGC
```

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4736626/how-can-i-generate-all-ordered-combinations-of-length-k-in-perl

Comment: The regular expression can't match something that isn't there.

Comment: There are over 4,000 different six-character combinations of four characters. Do you really want 4,000 lines of output, most of them zeroes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `uniq -c` counts the number of times a line occurs, it can't possibly return 0. The requested change requires a complete rewrite.

```
perl -e'
   while (<>) {
      ++$counts{$_} for /(?=([ATCG]{6}))/g;
   }

   for my $seq (glob("{A,C,G,T}" x 6)) {
      printf("%7d %s\n", $counts{$seq}, $seq);
   }
' "$file" >"${base}_hexhits_6mer.txt"
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is to build a hash of occurrence counts for each pattern, and then print the count of all possible patterns

This program uses the `glob` trick to generate a list of all possible six-character strings formed from A, T, C and G

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

my @files = qw/ e_coli.fa /;

my %counts;

for my $file ( @files ) {

    open my $fh, '<', $file or die qq{Unable to open "$file" for input: $!};

    while ( <$fh> ) {
        ++$counts{$1} while /(?= ( [ATCG]{6} ) ) /gx;
    }
}

for my $pattern ( glob '{A,T,C,G}' x 6 ) {
    printf "%4d %s\n", $counts{$pattern} // 0, $pattern;
}
```

Comment: '{A,C,G,T}' x 6 It is really great.

Answer (score 1):

In case you have a lot of data and you need something a little faster, here's a C solution:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void reader(FILE* in, unsigned long hist[4096]) {
  for (unsigned long key=0, count=0;;) {
    switch(getc(in)) {
      case EOF:                      return;
      case 'A': key <<= 2;           break;
      case 'C': key <<= 2; key += 1; break;
      case 'G': key <<= 2; key += 2; break;
      case 'T': key <<= 2; key += 3; break;
      default:  count=0;             continue;
    }
    if (count == 5) ++hist[key & 0xFFF];
    else ++count;
  }
}

int putkey(FILE* out, unsigned long key) {
  char s[6];
  for (int j=6; j--; key >>= 2) s[j] = "ACGT"[key&3];
  return fprintf(out, "%.6s", s); 
}

void writer(FILE* out, unsigned long hist[4096]) {
  for (unsigned long key = 0; key < 4096; ++key) {
    fprintf(stdout, "%7lu ", hist[key]);
    putkey(out, key);
    putchar('\n');
  }
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  FILE* in = stdin;
  if (argc > 1) in = fopen(argv[1], "r");
  if (!in) { perror(argv[1]); exit(1); }
  unsigned long hist[4096] = {0};
  reader(in, hist);
  writer(stdout, hist);
  return 0;
}
```

It took a bit less than half a second to process a 31MB fastq sample (which, as it happens, includes all 4096 possible six-character sequences); the Perl solutions took 12 seconds (fugu) and 18 seconds (ikegami/borodin), respectively.

Comment: I could definitely speed up my solution (by using nested loops instead of `glob`, and maybe by replacing the regex with `substr`), but the OP seem to want something he could easily place in another script, so I went with conciseness. Obviously, it still wouldn't be nearly as fast as this.

Comment: @ikegami: hard to believe that glob call is a major contributor to the execution time, but you should definitely fix the quotes; I had to change them to " to avoid terminating the surrounding shell quotes. Fwie, I was also aiming at concision but that means something else in C :-) Sometimes Perl is competitive but I suspect this isn't going to be one of them. However, fugu's answer seems to suggest that substr would help. In this C prog, I use a sliding window to avoid even substr; that wouldn't be a natural idiom in Perl, I think. Anyway, it wasn't meant as a criticism.

Answer (score 0):

What you're asking to do is much more complicated. To know what you **haven't** seen requires that you first know **all the possible combinations** of characters, that you can then filter against.

Here, I use a sliding window approach using [substr](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/substr.html) in Perl to find tally all "seen" `ATCG` characters in a string of `As`, `Ts`, `Cs` and `Gs` (as read from `__DATA__`) in a hash. These are then sorted, so that the most commonly observed 6-mer is shown first, and printed out.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @bases = qw/ A G C T /;

my %data; 

for my $a1(@bases){
    for my $a2(@bases){
        for my $a3(@bases){ 
            for my $a4(@bases){
                for my $a5(@bases){
                    for my $a6(@bases){
                        $data{"$a1$a2$a3$a4$a5$a6"} = 0;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

my $nucs = <DATA>; 

my $len = length($nucs);

for (my $i = 0; $i <= $len - 6; $i++) {
     my $kmer = substr($nucs, $i, 6);
     next if $kmer =~ tr/ACGT//c;
     $data{$kmer}++; # populate hash with "seen" 6-mers
}

# print out sorted hash
foreach my $seq (sort { $data{$b} <=> $data{$a} } keys %data ){
    print "$seq,$data{$seq}\n";
}

__DATA__
ATGCCCGTCGTAGTCATGCATGCATCGATCGATGCATGCTACGTGTTGT
```

There is clearly going to be a better/prettier way of calculating all permutations of characters in a string than what I've done, but it works.

As Borodin says, this prints out mostly variations of "unseen" strings.

Comment: This turns out to be faster than the borodin and ikegami's solution, at least on my machine, but it matches substrings which do include letters outside of the alphabet (in particular, newline characters).

Comment: @rici - interesting. Should have fixed the issue with matching non-ATCG characters

Comment: `next unless 'A|G|C|T'` is a no-op because `'A|G|C|T'` is a simple string which is always *true*.

Comment: Sorry, achieving what?